# Generating Coordinates for KML file

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to create a KML file that will overlay buildings on a map. I have a lot of buildings so there will be a lot of coordinates to figure out. Is there a tool that can help out with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you already have the addresses of these buildings.  To generate the coordinates of these automatically, you can put the addresses in a single file and write a few lines of code to iterate through calling something like the GeoNames web service

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

which will geocode them for you.  While their basic service is free, they also have a premium service:

http://www.geonames.org/commercial-webservices.html